# My worksite keeps adding to my job's requirements.

Tags: job-change, ethics

I've been working at a Mental Health agency for a while and recently they've been adding more and more to the responsibilities of the job. As our job takes on more and more responsibilities, the latest addition has me the most worried. We're now being told that it's mandatory to be on-call after-hours in shifts.

With so many employees, my shift would only come up a couple times a year, but each shift requires being on-call for a full week. While on-call, we can be called to the hospital at any hour of the day or night, week and weekend, and each time you go to the hospital you're there for several hours.

I feel like this impacts my ability to work effectively during my full-time schedule during the day, and had I know this would become a requirement of my job, I would have never accepted the position.

So my question is, is there anything I can do to fight this, should I seek legal counsel? It feels unethical to me to keep tacking on more and more requirements.

Thank you to anyone who responds.

Comment: I'm guessing that these requirements are being added to everyone, and not just you? Are you a part of a union?

Comment: legal advice is off topic for this q&a site

Comment: Ask for a raise.

Comment: We have no union, and I'm not asking for legal advice, I only want to know if this is a situation where I should seek legal advice. And our company hasn't allowed raises for around 10 years now, so that's not an option. But thank you all for your suggestions. :)

Comment: Did anyone suggest limiting the on-call time to 2-3 days at a time rather than a week. That would be less stressful (and tiring) and possibly easier to get someone to trade a day here or there.

Comment: If you're in Europe, it would be illegal for your employer to require you to work a full day after you've worked during the night.

Answer (score 6):

> had I know this would become a requirement of my job, I would have
>   never accepted the position.

Job requirements evolve over time. This happens in most jobs. If you look closely at a written offer letter, you'll almost always see a phrase along the lines of "... and other tasks as required."

If this new couple-of-times-per-year requirement is truly a deal-breaker for you, then you should certainly find a new job, then hand in your resignation for this one.

I've done the same when my job requirements changed in ways that simply didn't work for me. That said, in my current position we were told a few years back that we would be on call in a rotation. It hasn't turned out to be very burdensome so far.

> So my question is, is there anything I can do to fight this

First, make sure this is really mandatory. Talk with your boss. Explain your position, and find out if any alternatives exist. Then try to come up with a convincing argument why this new requirement should apply to others, but not to you, or why the company should handle this requirement in some other way.

During your discussion, you might also find out that when you are on call and actually are required to work off-hours, you are free to come in late the next day. Many companies implement modified rules for those on-call - perhaps your company does as well, or could be convinced to do so.

As @Myles points out - discuss alternatives, such as letting folks who want extra pay to cover the on-call requirement in exchange for an on-call bonus.

> should I seek legal counsel? It feels unethical to me to keep tacking
>   on more and more requirements.

If you are in a union, you should talk with your union rep and see if this requirement violates your contractual rules or not.

Depending on your locale, legal counsel might be of help. In my part of the world (the US), it would seem to be unlikely.

While it may be unpleasant, changing requirements are simply the way things work in many circumstances. Imagine if a business could never change any of their practices because it might deviate from someone's original job requirements. I suspect a lot more people would be fired, and simply replaced with someone who is given a new set of job requirements.

Comment: +1 for checking alternatives.  There may be a co-worker who would prefer the chance for call in pay.

Comment: Thank you very much. Unfortunately, there's not much that can be done in the way of checking for alternatives. It's become mandatory simply because they could not get any volunteers to take it on for extra pay, so they're forcing it on to the rest of us.

Comment: Also, we're not in a union. We're in the US, and I've thought about going to Legal Aid for help, but I don't know if this will be helpful or worth the time to investigate. 

Thank you for your help. It sounds like it's simply time to move on. It'll take some time to adjust, but thank you very much for your advice!